# How to add possibility getting data in drop down list between two classes which are in relationship?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, html.dropdownlistfor

In the program I have student and course tables and there is a relationship between them. How to make it possible to choose which course to include in the drop-down list when adding a student to the database?

```
 Student class:
        public int StudentID { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }

    Subject class:
     public int SubjectID { get; set; }
     public String SubjectName { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
```

If anyone has a simple example, I will be happy to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the 2nd dropdown on the 1st dropdown's selectedindexchanged event. (using the selectedvalue/text of the first dropdown to filter the results of the 2nd dropdown)